# how to stop meteor from auto merging my css files?

Tags: css, meteor, merge, meteor-blaze

I have 2 html files linked to each other and have different css files for each of them, but meteor merges them automatically. 
How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Meteor merges CSS to optimize its network delivery.
If you want to choose the order your stylesheets have in the merged CSS you may need to :
- Use a language as SASS, LESS or Stylus which allow to generate css so you could do `@import 'imports/ui/yourstylesheet.scss'` to `@import` files in the order you want. Note that if you choose to use a language as SASS or LESS you need to put your sass/less files that you want to import into /imports so you manually import them (puting files anywhere else than in /imports makes your files automatically imported). And `import` these files via a SASS/LESS/stylus file in the `/client` folder.
OR
- Put your css in `/client` folder and understand the Meteor's rules to choose in which order your css get loaded :

> The JavaScript and CSS files in an application are loaded according to
>   these rules:
>
> Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent directories,
>   so that files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded first, and files
>   in the root directory are loaded last.
>
> Within a directory, files are loaded in alphabetical order by
>   filename.
>
> After sorting as described above, all files under directories named
>   lib are moved before everything else (preserving their order).
>
> Finally, all files that match main.* are moved after everything else
>   (preserving their order).

OR
- You put your `.css` in the `/imports` directory (so Meteor doesn't import them automatically so you can choose in which order you load css files). And you import your `css` via a `.js` (javascript) file put into `/client` (as files into `/client` are loaded on your browser). In the `.js` file you do `import '/imports/ui/mystylesheet.css'` to import your css.

The cons of the three methods are respectively :
- You have to learn a language if you don't know any of these languages : stylus less or sass.
- Relying on complex rules to choose the order your css get loaded is probably not maintainable and oblige you to have specific names for your css
- `css` files loaded within a `.js` file are put in a `<style>` tag inside the DOM instead of being loaded in a separate `.css` file (which is not recommended). Besides the css loaded this way doesn't use the toolchain offered by Meteor plugins (compression of CSS, add pre-vendor prefixed to maximize the compatibility of your css and whatever the plugin you have offers you).

Comment: Seems like it would be really nice if there was an option to disable merging for development purposes...

Answer (score 1):

You can carefully change the order of load. Such as to make one override the other.

For example consider the following file structure

```
|-client
|-imports
  |-ui
     |-page1
       |-page1.html
       |-page1.js
       |-page1.css
     |-page2
       |-page2.html
       |-page2.js
       |-page3.css
```

Here, page1.js will import page1.css and this css will be applied to the template in page1.html

Similarly, page2.js can import page2.css and the same will be applied when the page2.html is rendered.

Comment: I think this structure is good enough for me, but what if I decide to create a page1.scss, it will be processed and included or there is another setup to handle those files?

Comment: I am sorry. I have not worked with scss before. I guess, if you put in the processors( or they may be included by default) it should work without any special handling of files.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your css class to the template when calling the route if you are using the iron router.

```
 Router.route('/addMemberProfile',{
 onBeforeAction: function () {
 $('body').addClass('your required class for this template');

  this.next();
 },
```